# how to find operator name from website phone no. search page in android application?

Tags: android, url, search

I need to find operator name from phone no. using this [website](https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer) in my android application.
Requesting and parsing HTML in the application works fine.

When I query request string from the app:

address: .https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/en/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer?&_*rp*/pts.SearchNumber_**ndc=70**&_*rp*/pts.SearchNumber_**operator=Tele2+Sverige+AB**&_*rp*/pts.SearchNumber_**telnumber=4264128**

I need to specify 'operator name' ..which is wierd I guess.

The problem is **no matter which number** (ndc-telnumber) I enter if I specify **a operator name** in the request string the resulting webpage shows **that operator name**.

Here are some numbers to test:
073-3355433 = Telenor Sverige AB
073-6107353 = Tele 2 Sverige AB
070-3999266 = TeliaSonera Sverige AB
073-2404070 = Glocalnet AB

How can I find the proper operator name for a specific number?

Thanks for your any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the site that prevent things from working:

1. It needs a cookie for the POST to work.
2. The operator name is actually not returned as part of the page, it is returned as part of a location redirect (302).

This chunk of code does what you want (I was dodging work, so I actually tidied it up for you): it hits the main page, fetches/extracts the cookie returned, posts the area code and number to the website and then intercepts the Location header and pulls out the operator name. Note that the area code is not always 3-digits (so for example for **073-3355433** you would do `String operatorName = findOperator("73","3355433");`.

```
String findOperator(String ndc, String number)
    {           
        String parameters = "action=search&ndc="+ndc+"&number="+number+"&search=S%F6k";
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int code = 0;
        String response = null;
        try {
            java.net.URI u = new java.net.URI("https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer");
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.toURL().openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7500);
            httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(7500);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpUrlConnection.connect();
            String cookie = httpUrlConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            u = new java.net.URI("https://nummertjanster.pts.se/actionrequest/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer?__ac_/pts.SearchNumber");
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.toURL().openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7500);
            httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(7500);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.connect();
            outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(parameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            httpUrlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            try {
                inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //andrologger.warn("An error occurred while POSTing to " + url, e);
            }

            code = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
            response = httpUrlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
            if(response != null){
                response = response.split("&")[2].split("=")[1];
            }
        }catch(Exception e1){
            android.util.Log.v("Configuration","Exception: "+e1.getMessage(), e1);
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(outputStream);
            closeQuietly(httpUrlConnection);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Tested it on my phone and it works fine: let me know how it works for you.

Comment: It worked like a charm. It will save my project. I want to give my project fee to you.

Comment: Hehehehe. I'll settle for the bounty. It was actually moderately interesting getting around that restriction.

Comment: Firebug is the way, the truth and the light for stuff like this: turn it on, set it to persist, and look at the headers.

Comment: @Femi to my surprise today i discover that the function is not working anymore. they included jsessionid=C7A4177BC10986FCC1043494193B4E9C? in the search string. would u please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

It clearly doesn't work restfully. You'll have to find another way.

Perhaps imitate the form post that the page is doing: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

*EDIT* this doesn't work

Pretty simple:

```
https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer?&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_ndc=PUT_AREA_NUMBER_HERE&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_operator=xxno_operatorxx&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_telnumber=PUT_NUMBER_HERE
```

i.e.

```
 https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer?&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_ndc=696&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_operator=xxno_operatorxx&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_telnumber=1788300
```

Comment: I tried this, It doesn't work. It always shows what you put in the  'SearchNumber_operator=xxno_operatorxx'field. It you put your name it will show that!

Comment: Are you sure, try my example (the i.e.) it gives back the operator

Comment: I am sure. I put this: https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer?&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_ndc=696&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_operator=xxno_operatorxx&__rp_/pts.SearchNumber_telnumber=1788300 and get no operator.

Comment: Ah yeah, was my translation gives you "Operator missing" but that's not the text you put in :-D

Comment: You can try putting "FUNNY" as operator. Resulting page will show that

Comment: I wonder how it is working from the website, as I don't need to put operator name there!

Comment: Any indication about 'another way'? :(

Comment: If you can imitate a form post with the variables ndc and number, then you could get the source back and parse it for the operator.

Comment: Thanks! But also Please let me know if you find even more specific link

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient Is exactly what you want to do

Comment: It throws exception in the first place: java.net.UnknownHostException: nummertjanster.pts.se when resolving the address: HttpPost("https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer")

Comment: the most important thing is never stop questioning - einestine :D